# Running Python on Ubuntu Shell

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am trying to run python on Ubuntu. *ADDED: It's a double boot system with Windows.*

If I type python on the shell, it opens python. But I want to run a python file.
I have my python (.py) file saved on windows Desktop.

On Windows when I run a .py file in my command prompt, I just have to change directory to Desktop then type python `myfile.py` and the code runs successfully.

When I try to do that same thing in Ubuntu, it does not work. I made a Desktop directory in Ubuntu using the mkdir function.

Now, when I type python myfile.py, I get the error:

> python: can't open file 'myfile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory

I tried typing python on the Ubuntu shell then dragging the `myfile.py` file `(~$ python C:\Users\username\Desktop\myfile.py)`, it used to run and then close the answer right away, but now I would get the error

> python: can't open file 'C:UsersusernameDesktopmyfile.py': [Errno 2]
>   No such file or directory

Can anyone tell me what are the exact steps I need to do to fix this?

EDIT:

Here is what I am writing from the answers below:

~$ python /home/username/Desktop/myfile.py

Yet, I am getting this error:

python: can't open file '/home/username/Desktop/myfile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

EDIT 2**

So here is something new: 
if I write

python /home/username/Desktop myfile.py

I get this error

/usr/bin/python: can't find 'main' module in '/home/username/Desktop

If I write

python /home/username/myfile.py

I do not get an error, but I do not get any output either. Ubuntu just goes to the next line $

Comment: Are you using the Windows Subsystem for Linux, perhaps? Looks like you may have copy-pasted a file path from the Windows side. Try accessing through `/mnt/c/Users/[You]/Desktop`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strange on Ubuntu your path starts with `c:\`...
On `Ubuntu` user folders are usually in `/home`, user folder can be referenced by `~`, so IMHO `python ~/Desktop/myfile.py` should work in your environment.

EDIT: noted you made `Desktop` folder, not original `Desktop`, that way when you are in that folder type `pwd` it will show full path, then put it in `python PATH/myfile.py` (and just in case you may type `ls` to show list of files in current folder on Linux to check you are indeed in the right folder where your program is).

ADDED: after discussion it turned to be double boot system, `mount` showed mounted windows disk and `file.py` was found and run!

Comment: After trying your suggestion: ~$ python ~/Desktop/myfile.py, I still get this error
python: can't open file '/home/username/Desktop/myfile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @usernew, is it working now? if not, after your made folder with `mkdir` how did you put your file there? Have you typed `ls` - did it show your file in the folder?

Comment: I thought I made a Desktop directory when I wrote mkdir Desktop, but I didnt write mkdir myfile.py? How do I put my file in the home directory or in the Desktop directory; I thought mkdir Desktop did not actually make a Desktop directory. When I write cd Desktop then ls -l , I get nothing

Comment: @usernew, depends on where it is now I guess. Can you find out? Have you typed it in text editor on Ubuntu or is it on USB stick?

Comment: My file saved to my desktop. I do not know how to put it into Ubuntu

Comment: @usernew, by your answer I guess you run Ubuntu via Oracle VM on Windows, am I right?

Comment: No, I am not running it on vm

Comment: @usernew, if not VM, I suggest your read something like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391915/where-is-the-path-to-the-current-users-desktop-directory-stored or/and please add some screenshots to your question.

Comment: I put the file in my current directory and when I run it I do not get any errors, but I just cant see the results of my code now.

Comment: @ usernew, I guess it's from comments to other answer - empty file. IMHO better edit the question to show with pictures/screenshots where your python code is now.

Comment: But the file runs and outputs answers as it runs when I run the code through cmd prompt

Comment: @usernew, have you copied text to that new file? touch just makes empty file.

Comment: Oh, if I run the python code on cmd prompt, I get answers printed out as the code runs. But, if I run that same python code on Ubuntu, I just get the next line $. So I know my code runs but I don't see anything. I have written print(time) but that only prints if running code in cmd prompt not in Ubuntu. I am new to Ubuntu so I am trying it using code that runs in cmd prompt first to make sure I now how to use Ubuntu for my other coding. Thanks for your help btw

Comment: So here is something new: if I write $ python /home/username/Desktop myfile.py I get this error /usr/bin/python: can't find 'main' module in '/home/username/Desktop'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199031/discussion-between-marisha-and-usernew).

Answer (score 2):

Backslash '\' is an escape character, in Unix it will not be used if you put it in a path. It results in your error of path not found.
Use slash '/', your code should run.

It is weird that you have a path for windows, in Unix you should not have this type of path...
Open a terminal, go to the folder with your python script. Use `pwd` in the terminal to know the exact location and then copy the path and use the following (I take an example here):

```
python PATHTOYOURPYTHONSCRIPT/mypythonscript.py
```

Comment: What was the result of `pwd` when you were in the correct folder?

Comment: pwd gave me /home/username

Comment: can you try `python /home/username/myfile.py` ?

Comment: Yes, that works but it does not show any answers. It just goes to the next line

Comment: Your python script does not have any output. Open /home/username/myfile.py and add a print statement (like `print ('Hello')`). Now when executing it should print `Hello`. If you want to display a certain variable, use `print (nameofthevariable)`

Comment: It does have an output, because when I run the same code in my cmd prompt, I get the output. It just won't output in Ubuntu for some reason

Comment: Oh... are you by any chance using a unix virtual machine on a Windows computer?

Comment: No, I am not using a virtual machine

Comment: I don' understand then, cmd prompt is something that is on Windows. Could you explain a bit more? Do you have something working on Windows that is not working on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use windows path representation in Linux. Windows and Linux has different path representations.

In windows, you can use C:\ but in Linux it's just a / which is used to denote the root directory.

In the terminal, type 'pwd' where your python file is present in Ubuntu and you'll see the output as '/home/username/Desktop' which is not like windows.

So you need to run like, 'python /home/username/Desktop/my file.py'.

If you need to access the file present in the windows partition, you need to mount the windows partition. This can be done using the Files app present in Ubuntu. After that, you can navigate to /mnt/media/ and find your file.

Comment: I get this error stiil: python: can't open file '/home/c/Desktop/myfile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Do you have a file named myfile.py under your desktop directory in Ubuntu?

Comment: No, and I do not know how to add it into Ubuntu

Comment: You can create a file using the touch command. 'touch myfile.py' will create a file. Now, you can paste your contents to the file and execute it using the above method.

Comment: So, I wrote touch myfile.py on my homedirectory. Then I wrote python /home/username/myfile.py and I didn't get any errors. But the problem is how can I view the answers now. In my command prompt it would write out the answers

Comment: You've to put your code inside the file which you've created and then execute the file.

Comment: so there is no way to see how python runs the file, ie see the answers or see if python ran correctly or see if there are any python errors?

Comment: Since your file is empty, it didn't throw any errors and output. Try typing 'print "Hello world!"'  In the file and execute it.

Comment: Can you share the code which is present in you file?

Comment: I tested the code in cmd prompt and it works fine and it outputs the answers. Was I supposed to add something to the code in my file?

Comment: Can you make sure the code whichever you executed in the command prompt is present in the file which you're trying to execute in Ubuntu?

Comment: Is there a command in ubuntu that opens a file, just so I can double check?

Comment: So here is something new: if I write $ python /home/username/Desktop myfile.py I get this error 
/usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in '/home/username/Desktop'

Comment: You can open a file using 'gedit myfile.py' to see the contents in a notepad (similar to windows)